# Add a group id to a many to many bridge table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I currently have 2 following tables

```
Course {
  id: int
  name: string
}

Subject {
  id:int
}
```

There is a many to many relationships b/w the two which calls for a bridge table.

```
CourseSubjects {
  course_id:int
  subject_id:int
}
```

Now, the problem is that I need to add a group id to each record in the CourseSubjects table. I am unsure to put it in the CourseSubjects itself or create another separate table?.

Comment: What is the intended meaning of the `group_id`? In other words, what is it grouping?

Comment: Why do you think that you need this id in the junction table?

Comment: you need such a  group_id only  if you need to refer to a row, or need other sql function that ned that reference, but usually you don't need it, as the bridge table is only a link between two(or more( tables  and those links are used in queries

Comment: The subject act as a prerequisite to a course. So each entry in CourseSubjects table means a prerequisite for a particular course. However, there is a requirement that these prerequisites can be in groups such as to satisfy a course prerequisites you might only need Subject A or Subject B but Subject C is compulsory as well. So each group id will act as like a group in which if one subject is met then that group is satisified.